# HTML password pattern with minimal requirements

Tags: html, input, passwords

I've a small problem with a pattern for an input password.

I need the password to have this pattern but I can't find a solution for this problem.

The password must meet the following criteria:

- 8 characters minimal length.
- Begin with a number.
- Finish with an uppercase letter.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `[0-9].{6,}[A-Z]`

Comment: As irrational and arbitrary password requirements come, that is pretty irrational and arbitrary.

Comment: @JJJ These requirements ensure people don't choose too predictable passwords such as "Manuel1988"

Comment: Complex password rules will usually not lead to more safe passwords, important is only a minimum length. People cannot remember tons of strong passwords, and such rules can interfere with good password schemes. People can get very inventive to bypass such rules, e.g. by using weak passwords like "Password-2018" or in your case "2018PASSWORD". Often you end up with weaker passwords instead of stronger ones. Recently NIST published an [official paper](https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/sp800-63b.html), advising against such rules, and against its former recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `pattern` attribute of `input`:

```
 <input type="password" pattern="[0-9].{6,}[A-Z]" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use regular expression.
For example ^[0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,16}[A-Z]$

Answer (score -1):

I would prefer to use JavaScript for validations

Edit

I was able to get the regex try this 
     `[0-9].{6,}[a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]{};':"\|,.<>/?][A-Z]$`